# How do I correct Intern npm install failure in fixdeps.js

Tags: node.js, intern

I am getting the error below when trying to install the Intern test framework. I have tried clearing the npm cache, restarting machine, etc. The file that the error says already exists does not exist. Does it perhaps have to do with the fact I am running node v0.11.13? I know some packages won't work with anything above .10.xx. Or, perhaps it is something else?

```
> intern@2.1.1 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\intern
> node support/fixdeps.js

fs.js:755
  return binding.symlink(preprocessSymlinkDestination(destination, type),
                 ^
Error: EEXIST, file already exists 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\intern\
node_modules\dojo'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:755:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\intern\support\fixdeps.js:27:6
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\intern\support\f
ixdeps.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
npm ERR! intern@2.1.1 install: `node support/fixdeps.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the intern@2.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the intern package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node support/fixdeps.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls intern
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "intern"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, indeed, due to the use of Node 0.11.13. Specifically, there appears to be a bug in how Node's `path` module works in 0.11.13.

Near the top of Intern's `support/fixdeps.js` script, a path is created using `path.join`:

```
var expected = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules');
```

When running `fixdeps.js` on a test system (Windows 7, Node.js 0.11.13), `__dirname` starts with `C:\`. However, the path returned by `path.join` starts with `c:\` (lowercase C). This difference in case causes a path comparison later in the script to return an incorrect value.

When `fixdeps.js` is run under Node.js 0.10.26, `path.join` does not change the case of the drive letter, and the script runs correctly.

Comment: Fascinating. Nice catch! Have you filed an issue with Node?

Comment: An issue already exists for this (https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7031). The suggested fix seems to be to use `path.normalize` on everything before doing a comparison. That makes sense when using user-defined paths, but I really would have expected Node's own `__dirname` property to already be normalized.